# JSF with Multiple Tabs

Tags: jsf, tabs

A JSF application needs to open several tabs which are handled by same JSF CDI Bean Class.

I have tried to use ViewScope, yet when more than one tab is open by clicking the "Duplicate Tab" feature in the browser, they all share one bean object. Is there any way we can have each tab managed by a different instance of a JSF CDI bean?

For the time being, we use session sope controllers and advice users NOT to open multiple tabs for the application. This advice has made the application not so user friendly. These days users are used to opening multiple tabs by clicking the duplicate tab feature. Other technologies support managing data through multiple tabs seamlessly in such cases. So why can't JSF support data entry using multiple tabs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Comment: I went through that answer before deciding to go for the view scope. The View Scope is ideal for my situation, but duplicating tabs causes confusion.